# Entering Data from Labels and a Gridview to a database at the same time (WebApps)

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio, gridview

Goal:

In one database (Inputs) have two tables of data (UserInfo and    Items). I want to send their combined data to a third table (Records)    in another database (Outputs).

- The UserInfo table only has one row per order.
- The Items table can have mulitple rows per order.
- After each order of the application's function, UserInfo and Items
  are reset (meaning that when selecting data from UserInfo and Items to sendover to Records, all data will be selected from each table because only data from the current order will exist).
- The Records table is never reset.

**SOLUTION**

Instead of writing the data to the gridviews then writing to the final table, I instead found much more success in merging the tables before handhand with sql statements in query builder.
This way I could write the data to the display objects and the final table.

aspx:

```
<h2>
            <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="lblPurpose" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </h2>
    <br />
    <center>
        <p>
            &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblDest" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:GridView ID="grdDisplay" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No Data Found" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid"
                BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ID" Width="70%" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ITEM_NUM" HeaderText="Item Number" SortExpression="ITEM_NUM">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ITEM_DESC" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="ITEM_DESC">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ITEM_QTY" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="ITEM_QTY">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringInputDB %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ItmTable]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </p>
        <br />
    </center>
```

aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            MyDataUpdate();
        }

        void MyDataUpdate()
        {
            DataTable Table1 = new DataTable();
            DataRow Table1Row;
            DataTable Table2 = new DataTable();
            DataTable Table3 = new DataTable();

            string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Inputs"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(mainconn))
            {
                // get Table1 and row 1

                string strSQl = "Select * from UserInfo WHERE ID = ID";

                using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQl, con1))
                {
                    con1.Open();
                    Table1.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                    Table1Row = Table1.Rows[0];

                    // get 2nd table of data
                    cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ITEM_NUM = @ITEM_NUM";
                    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ITEM_NUM", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "ITEM_NUM";

                    Table2.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());

                    // now we take above information, and update to Table 3

                    string mainconn2 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Outputs"].ConnectionString;
                    using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(mainconn2))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Records where ID = ID", con2))
                        {
                            con2.Open();
                            Table3.Load(cmdSQL2.ExecuteReader());

                            // add Table1 and Table 2 to Table 3

                            DateTime MyTimeNow = DateTime.Now;

                            foreach (DataRow T2Row in Table2.Rows)
                            {
                                // start new row in table 3
                                DataRow MyNewRow = Table3.NewRow();

                            MyNewRow["User"] = Table1Row["User"];
                            MyNewRow["Dest"] = Table1Row["Dest"];
                            MyNewRow["Time"] = Table1Row["Time"];
                            // MyNewRow["Time"] = MyTimeNow;
                            MyNewRow["Purpose"] = Table1Row["Purpose"];

                            MyNewRow["ITEM_NUM"] = T2Row["ITEM_NUM"];
                            MyNewRow["ITEM_DESC"] = T2Row["ITEM_DESC"];
                            MyNewRow["ITEM_QTY"] = T2Row["ITEM_QTY"];

                            // Add this new row to table 3
                            Table3.Rows.Add(MyNewRow);
                            }

                            // send (save) these new rows to the database3
                            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL2);
                            SqlCommandBuilder daU = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

                            da.Update(Table3);

                        }

                        //Populate Labels

                        lblUser.Text = Table1Row["user"].ToString();
                        lblDest.Text = Table1Row["Dest"].ToString();
                        lblTime.Text = Table1Row["Time"].ToString();


                        // Populate Gridview

                        grdDisplay.DataSource = Table2;
                        grdDisplay.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to add new rows to the database (those last 3 columns), or are you wanting to edit existing data in the gv? On the other hand, if you adding rows, then no rows would exist then right? So, which is this? Add rows, or edit rows. And since you suggest you have the gv filled out, then this would suggest edit of rows? Or are you wanting to add rows here? In other words, that gv would need a add row button, you add a row, edit, and then when you save - all 3 rows + the 4 static rows would be added to database? This is not hard either way - but need to know if you adding, or editing?

Comment: And if you adding, then we assume you need some kind of button to add a new row to the gv that you can edit, and then eventually save with the 3 columns you just changed/edit + the 4 columns are then to be saved as NEW rows to the database, right?

Comment: I do not want to edit the Gridview. The Gridview and the Labels are already populated with data. I want to take that data and submit it into a database for record keeping. This database is not meant to displayed on the page.

Comment: Ok, so whatever we have displayed in the Gv + the 4 other fields are then to be added to a given table say on hitting a submit button. So, we not adding rows to the GV - but upon some kind of save, we are to create new rows in a table upon save? Or are we to update existing rows in the gv (along with the labels for each row?). So only part not clear is if we are to add these combined 7 columns as new rows to a given table, or we are trying to update the existing rows in the gv with the 4 labels data then? (so is this a update operation, or a add rows operation we want here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you suggest no editing of the grid?

In effect, the GV does not even matter then, does it?

I mean, we can have this code to load the GV.

And ALSO save the data back to the database.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadData();
        }
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
         // code here to load up labels - don't care how you do this
         // 

        // now code to load GV and send labels to database.
        // so send Label Values to be entered into database
        using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string sql2 = "select * From RECORD";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(sql2,con2))
            {
                DataTable rstData = New DataTable();
                con2.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                grdDisplay.DataSource = rstData;
                grdDisplay.DataBind();

                // gv loaded - so now update the data rows in the grid
                // with lables

                foreach (DataRow Dr in rstData.Rows)
                {
                    Dr["User"] = lblUser.Text;
                    Dr["Dest"] = lblDest.Text;
                    Dr["Time"] = Convert.ToDateTime(lblTime.Text);
                }

                // send changes back to database
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
                SqlCommandBuilder daU = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                da.Update(rstData);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, of course you could move the update (database save code) to say a separate bit of code - maybe the GV is to be "reviewed" and then you hit ok?

In that case, I would persist the rstData.

eg:

## Edit: Remember to define and scope rstData to the whole page class

```
    DataTable rstData = new DataTable();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadData();
            Session["rstData"] = rstData;
        }
        else
            rstData = Session["rstData"] as DataTable;
    }
```

So now after "review" or whatever, you have this code behind that confirm button:

```
        using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string sql2 = "select * From RECORD";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(sql2))
            {
                // now update the data rows in the grid
                // with labels data
                foreach (DataRow Dr in rstData.Rows)
                {
                    Dr["User"] = lblUser.Text;
                    Dr["Dest"] = lblDest.Text;
                    Dr["Time"] = Convert.ToDateTime(lblTime.Text);
                }
                con2.Open();
                // send changes back to database
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
                SqlCommandBuilder daU = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                da.Update(rstData);
            }
        }
    }
```

So, by persisting the rstData - then the GV and the rstData are ONE and the SAME.

As a result, you can just loop that rstData - and then send all updates back to the database with the above code. Note how we don't' have to loop, or execute or build multiple update statements - we update the datatable, and then in one command send all changes back to database in one operation.

So, you don't have to have the rstData to the grid and the update of rstdata in the SAME routine. But you should persist the data table to ensure that the data table that fills/drives the GV is the same one used for the final update of the data table and the the sending (saving) of the rstData table back to the database.

## Edit #3: The data operations part

Ok, so our probem is really this:

I have table1 - one row.

I have table2 - can and will useally be several rows.

I have table3 - different database.

I need to take each row from table2 + values from table1, and output results to Table3 (new rows).

Now, HOW hard was the above question???

MORE imporant, note how this has ZERO but ABSOULTE ZERO to do with dispay of  some lables, and ZERO ZERO to do with some grid view.

WHY is the above concept important?

Well, answer this question:

How do you eat a elephant?

Answer: One bite at a time!!!!

So, after we do these database operations? Sure, have fun, display some labels, have fun, maybe fill out a grid view. but our data operation program is 100% SEPERATE from those labels, and 100% separate from that grid view.

So here is how the code can be laid out. I don't have your connections, don't have your tables, don't have a BOATLOAD of information.

However, all you need is the basic layout and logic here. As noted, this is "air code", but it should be close.

(and I suggest perhaps some links to cooking school, or even maybe truck driving school if the code that follows does not make sense). However, do feel 100% free to ask questions about the following code - I can't run it, don't have your data - don't really care. All you REALLY need is the basic logic and how you approach such probems. As noted, consider the truck driving school as your back up plan (since if you don't grasp how and why this data operations is 100% seperate from some lables or gv's on the web form then all hope here is lost!!).

So, the code should and would be somthing like this:
(and as noted, NEVER but NEVER ever forget the PostBack = false issue - failure to not use such code stubs on EVERY page will result in pages that you really can't write code into).

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            MyDataUpdate();
    }


    void MyDataUpdate()
    {

        DataTable Table1 = new DataTable();   // first table - will be one row
        DataRow Table1Row;

        DataTable Table2 = new DataTable();  // 2nd table - can be many rows

        DataTable Table3 = new DataTable();  // 3rd table - save to different database

        using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            // get Table1 and row 1

            // I don't know what critera you have here - we can't read your mind..
            // but we will assume that some critera exists - we get/want/have ONE row

            string strSQL = "SELECT * from Table1 WHERE ID = 134";

            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con1))
            {
                con1.Open();
                Table1.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                Table1Row = Table1.Rows[0];

                // get 2nd table of data
                // again, don't know your criteria
                // say a given City ? (again, whatever floats your boat
                cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table2 Where City = @City";
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Edmonton";

                Table2.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());


                // now we take above information, and update to Table 3

                using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST3))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmdSQL2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Table3 where ID = 0", con2))
                    {
                        con2.Open();
                        Table3.Load(cmdSQL2.ExecuteReader());

                        // now add information from table1, and 2 to this 3rd table

                        DateTime MyTimeNow = DateTime.Now;

                        foreach (DataRow T2Row in Table2.Rows)
                        {
                            // start new row in table 3
                            DataRow MyNewRow = Table3.NewRow();

                            MyNewRow["User"] = Table1Row["User"]; // or data 1???
                            MyNewRow["Dest"] = Table1Row["Dest"]; // or data 2???
                            MyNewRow["Time"] = Table1Row["Time"]; // or is this datetime?
                            // MyNewRow["Time"] = MyTimeNow; // or is this datetime?
                            MyNewRow["Purpose"] = Table1Row["Purpose"];


                            MyNewRow["ITEM_NUM"] = T2Row["ITEM_NUM"];
                            MyNewRow["ITEM_DESC"] = T2Row["ITEM_DESC"];
                            MyNewRow["ITEM_QTY"] = T2Row["ITEM_QTY"];

                            // Add this new row to table 3
                            Table3.Rows.Add(MyNewRow);
                        }

                        // ok, all rows added to table 3
                        // send (save) these new rows to the database3

                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL2);
                        SqlCommandBuilder daU = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

                        da.Update(Table3);

                    }

                    // ok, data operations done.
                    // now comes the float you boat, maybe show a pet cat picture.
                    // WE REALLY DO NOT CARE.

                    // I know, how about we fill out the 3 lables!!!!

                    lblUser.Text = Table1Row["user"].ToString();
                    lblDest.Text = Table1Row["Dest"].ToString();
                    // lblTime.Text = Table1Row["Time"].ToString(); // this might need formatting


                    // hey, maybe we want to show a picture of a dog?
                    // hey, I know, why not load up the grid with table2?

                    grdDisplay.DataSource = Table2;
                    grdDisplay.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241102/discussion-on-answer-by-albert-d-kallal-entering-data-from-labels-and-a-gridvie).

Comment: I apologize for not responding earlier, but I did manage to fix my issue by taking another approach. Instead of taking the data from the grid views, I merged the tables with sql statements and used the combined data to write to the desired table.